# How many people use my telegram bot?

Tags: count, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

I created a bot

**@WeatherPlusbot**

How do I know how many people use it?

Is there a way or "place" where you can count how many people have "installed" or currently use my bot?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately telegram doesn't provide such info. You should log the ID of any user, using your bot.

A simple solution could be to create a database with the user ID primary key, the registration timestamp and the last usage timestamp.

I use this kind of way so you have more rich statistics knowing the total users, the active users in the last day, week, how many users are registering lately etc

Answer (score 3):

You can't get this data from API at this time, you can log `/start` event to your own database, and count unique user send this command.