# How can I count how many users that have clicked /start on my telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram

I need a Python code to check how many users clicked /start on my telegram bot. How can I make the bot reply like this?
users: 23
I need to know the number of people that have clicked /start

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How many people use my telegram bot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46009961/how-many-people-use-my-telegram-bot)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic approach:

### #1

1. Connect your bot to a database if you haven't already.
2. Make an integer value (initially set to 0), say "`usercount`".
3. Go to the section of your code where you have written the response to the `/start` command.
4. Add code to increment the value in the database by `1`. (Code may vary depending on different database types)

### #2

This value would represent the no. of times the `/start` command has been executed. However, a single user may simply execute `/start` command indefinitely.

So, to make it user-specific and prevent a single user from being counted as multiple users, you can extend the code functionality. One way to do that is:

- Create another value in your database. (One that can store multiple values, like an array)
- Get the chat ID, if that isn't already present in the array, store it in the array and increment `usercount` by `1`
- If it is already present, ignore the increment part and simply continue with rest of your code

### #3

Now that you have set up the system, the last step is making a new command for telling you how many users have executed `/start` command.

1. Make a new command
2. Add code to fetch `usercount`
3. Output the value

---

Note that this is only a basic approach, there might be loopholes, and there might be better ones out there.